# How can i count how many while loop runs i need to get the certain combinatoin of elements?

Tags: python

Here is little lottery-like code I wrote. For example, I want to count how many while loops runs are required to get the certain order (for example, 4a67). I mean, [4,'a',6,7], like i have it in comb_list.

```
from random import choice

random_list = ['a','b','c','d',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

comb_list = []

while len(comb_list) < 4:
    ran_sel = choice(random_list)
    comb_list.append(ran_sel)
    
messege = f"{comb_list[0]}{comb_list[1]}{comb_list[2]}{comb_list[3]}"
print(messege)
```

Comment: `for attempt_num in itertools.count(1):`

Comment: You have a 1/14 chance of picking any element. 

Therefore, on average, you would expect output of `4a67` in `(1/14)^4` executions, or approximately, 0.0026% of times you ran the code

Answer (score 0):

> want to count how many while loops runs are required to get the certain order

Use a loop and keep generating until it matches

```
iterations = 0

while True:
    iterations += 1
    message = ''.join(random.choice(random_list) for _ in range(4))
    if message == '4a67':
        break

print(f'Took {iterations} iterations')
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you need, but I made this code. feel free to play around with it.

> here you go:

```py
from random import choice

random_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

comb_list = []
count = 0
while comb_list != [4, 'a', 6, 7]:
    count += 1
    comb_list = [choice(random_list) for something_should_go_here_or_maybe_not in range(4)]

print('It took', count, 'iterations to get: ', end='')
messege = ''.join(map(str, comb_list))
print(messege)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice

random_list = ['a','b','c','d',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
target = [4, 'a', 6, 7]

attempt_num = 1
while any(val != choice(random_list) for val in target):
    attempt_num += 1

print('attempt count: %d' % attempt_num)
```